# Accessing 'this' variable in function passed to setInterval/setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I'm creating a simple game with a character that can jump, move right, and move left.

I'm having trouble with the jump function, which uses a `setInterval`.

Here is the function:

```
 jumpUp: function (speed) {
        setInterval(function () {
            this.yPos += 10;
            this.playerElement.css("top", '-=' + 10);
            alert("dude, im not moving....so stop trying"); //for some reson, this line works and other dont.
        }, 100);
}
```

I should add that the code works without the `setInterval`. I really don't have any idea why it's not working when I add the `setInterval`.

My questions:

1. What is stopping this code from running?
2. Is `setInterval` a good way to make a character look like it jumping and landing?  Or should i use different method?

EDIT 1:

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7XyUL/)**

Comment: Would you post a jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: You have a scope problem, using "this" in the context of an anonymous function in setInterval => you lost the context of the jumpUp function.

Comment: `this` is resolving to `window` at runtime

Comment: use `console.log` instead of `alert`, it doesn't stall execution of the script

Comment: i added a fiddle of the class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is your use of `this`. When the function you pass to `setInterval` is called, `this` will be the global object (`window` in browsers). You need to preserve the `this` value from when you call `setInterval`. One way of doing this is to store the value of `this` into a variable, which will then be closed over by the anonymous function (which is a closure):

```
 jumpUp: function (speed) {
        var self = this;
        setInterval(function () {
            self.yPos += 10;
            self.playerElement.css("top", '-=' + 10);
        }, 100);
}
```

EDIT:

To answer your second question, a better approach to animating a sprite (like your character) is to store the character's velocity, and then have a single game loop that will calculate the next position of the sprite based on that information. A very simple example would look like:

```
// Somewhere else in the code:
function tick() {
    // move player by player.velocity.x and player.velocity.y

    // code to decelerate player gradually, stop player when they hit a wall/floor, etc...
    // A very simple example:
    if (player.velocity.y > 0) {
        player.velocity.y -= 1
    }

    // call next tick() (setTimeout, or preferably requestAnimationFrame)
}

// In the player code:
velocity: {x: 0, y: 0},
jumpUp: function () {
    this.velocity.y -= 10;
},
moveRight: function () {
    this.velocity.x += 10;
}
```

Comment: Good explanation George P. samy, his code suggestion and mine should work the same. If it works, give George P the credit for answering slightly sooner and including a good description!

Answer (score 1):

As darma and danronmoon pointed out, you have a scoping problem with this.

Try the following code:

```
jumpUp: function (speed) {
    var that = this;

    setInterval(function () {
        that.yPos += 10;
        that.playerElement.css("top", '-=' + 10);
    }, 100);
}
```

I added a variable, that, to maintain the reference to whatever this is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to your closure problem, this is probably going to cause choppy jumping.

Here's another pattern that watches the clock to see how much time has elapsed between each call to the function (`setInterval` is not consistent):

```
jumpUp: function (speed) // speed in pixels per second
{
    var last = +new Date();
    var c = this;
    var jumptick = function ()
    {
        var interval = +new Date() - last;
        c.yPos += speed * interval;
        c.playerElement.css("top", c.yPos);
        if (/* condition for reaching maximum height */) speed = -speed;
        if (! /* condition for reaching ground */) setTimeout(jumptick);
            // could add an interval but this will lead to fastest frame rate
    };
    jumptick();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setinterval is not a good way to achieve this because it will use a lot a ressources.
You also need to consider the framerate when you are moving your character, otherwise he will move fast on a fast machine/browser and slow on a slow machine.

A good method is using the requestAnimationFrame method. You can find a javascript file on google that will make it crossbrowser compatible.

Then, everytime your function is called, you will need to check the time elapsed between to frame and move your sprites accordingly. It's more work but that way, your game will run at the same pace on any machine.